# INSERT INTO with PHP $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, insert

I'm new to database development, and really struggling with formatting. For the life of me, I can't seem to flush out the errors. I have a simple html form that I am passing to my php file to submit to my local host. For whatever reason, I can't seem to add $_POST in the values. I'm sure I'm missing something, maybe someone on here can help.

Thanks in advance!

```
<form method="post" action="demo.php">
<input type="text" id="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname">
<input type="text" id="email">
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

My demo.php is:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = 
 'INSERT INTO
   test_tb (firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES
  (
   "echo $_POST['fname']",
   "echo $_POST['lname']",
   "echo $_POST['email']"
  )';

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
  ;
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind the variables. Ignore anyone who posts a solution that works with inputting `$_POST` directly into the query.

Comment: You don't need echo inside the query `echo $_POST['fname']`, you just pass your `$_POST` value

Comment: Since you're confused with how to add strings together, give the php man page about [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) a read. Look at my answer for the correct safe method to execute your query

Comment: By the way I just noticed your <form>, those `id` need to be `name` or else all of your `$_POST` will be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your form..
Look at your inputs; take this one for example:
`<input type="text" id="fname">`
This is missing the `name` attribute therefore, it won't be correctly set when you submit the form; it must be like so:
`<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">`

Secondly, if you want to concatenate a string, you don't use `echo`, `echo` is used for outputting text. To attach strings together in PHP you should read the manual page on [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Thirdly and most importantly;

Use prepare to input your data. Never pass $_POST directly into your query.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = 
 'INSERT INTO
   test_tb (firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES
  (
   ?,
   ?,
   ?
  )';
 //use ->prepare in favour of ->query
 if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    //bind your inputs
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['email']);    
   //execute the prepared query
   if($stmt->execute()){
      echo "New record created successfully";
   }
  //You had a random ';' here that I've commented out??
  //;
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   echo "</br>Stmt error: ".$stmt->error();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - great code! And thanks for the tims about name and mysqli prepare. However, when I submit the form I get a blank page that has says: Error: INSERT INTO test_tb (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ) - any ideas why?

Comment: @PhysicsIsRelativelyCool Sorry I was away yesturday so I didn't read your comment. I've inserted a better error debug output `echo "</br>Stmt error: ".$stmt->error();`. Double check you've made the changes to your form that I mention at the start of my answer :)